# Latency of inference using libtorch with multithreads and one thread on CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, libtorch

I use libtorch version=1.10.0 to inference my model on cpu(cenos, x86) with one thread, the latency is ~30ms while the latency is ~70ms when setting threads=64(system has 64 cores). Note: each thread has independent computing resources, and only using one thread for inference. e.g. at::set_num_threads(1), is that normal? Subconsciously think this is normal because the CPU becomes busy, but I wonder if there is a more detailed explanation? thanks.

is it possible to get the same inference latency with different threads?

Comment: If libtorch needs to start (spinup) threads there will be a latency before the new threads are constructed/started/scheduled. So expect some overhead, if you can use a threadpool that might help

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer thanks for your reply. I need to add clarification: I have used the threadpool to decode 10k wav files for ASR tasks.